# In rippled.cfg, what to use for [node_db] on Windows?

Tags: ripple, windows, ripple-client

I am trying to run rippled, but it is stating that I am missing [node_db] from rippled.cfg. In that file I can see

```
# Note that HyperLevelDB is unavailable on Windows platforms
#
[node_db]
type=HyperLevelDB
path=db/hyperldb
```

What should I put in for [node_db] on Windows?

Comment: This was asked and answered on the Ripple forums: https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time only SQLite is available on Windows platform, so the correct configuration is:

```
[node_db]
type=Sqlite
path=hashnode.db
```

Comment: I thought LevelDB was available on Windows.